# Get a Facebook page stream type

Tags: facebook-graph-api, stream, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I want to get all the stream of a Facebook fan page.

In my app, i want to display the "post" with a different template dipending on the type of the post.

But when i get the post with FQL or API the type is never the same, and for example for an event the type is "Status", for milestone the type is "status" or "photo".

Does someone know how can i get the real type of the "post"?

Thx for your help